# Word Add-in replace current document bytes

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js

I am sending the document as byte array to an API that modifies the file and gets me a new file as a byte array.

Is it possible to replace document that I am working with currently, with the document received from the API?

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert the byte array to a base64 string, then you can use the `Body.insertFileFromBase64` method (with the `Replace` option) to do what you want. There are lots of StackOverflow answers about converting byte arrays to base64 string. For more about the `Body.insertFileFromBase64` method, see [Body](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body).

Comment: This is a helpful response for my scenario which is similar. What I notice though is that if I use body.insertFileFromBase64 with the replace option the footer and some formatting is lost compared to using application.createDocument(base64Doc) where the doc formatting and footer are preserved. Is there a way to replace the entire contents of the current doc rather than just the body?